# Remove text from colour picker

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

The JavaFX colour picker is rather neat, but it always seems to display the text representation of the colour, as well as the colour itself:

[image: JavaFX colour dialog with text]

I'd like it without the text, just with the colour square, but can't seem to find a method to style it this way. The only thing that's come close I've tried so far is to restrict the width of the control so the text can't be shown:

```
picker.setMaxWidth(30);
```

...but that seems incredibly hacky, and still produces a "..." to the side of the button where the text has been trimmed off:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: @OctagonSoftware As pointed out in the answer, it is indeed possible, it just wasn't covered in that document!

Comment: My apologies, I've learned to believe that the docs have everything

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

colorpicker.setStyle("-fx-color-label-visible: false ;");

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Exactly what I was after - I always seem to miss the relevant CSS properties...

Comment: It took me a while, but I now look at the [CSS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#colorpicker) nearly as often as the API docs.

Comment: Good plan - I need to get into the habit of doing that more often!